# How to Connect to MySQL in R through SSH from a remote Ubuntu machine

Tags: mysql, r, ubuntu, ssh

I am really stuck in a weird situation and not able to make it since long back.
Here is the complete process am trying to execute:
1. Connecting to remote Ubuntu machine through SSH from windows 7 Machine - Doing this to automate some scripts
2. I have installed R on Ubuntu
3. Now trying to connect to remote MySQL (again using SSH) in R using RMySQL on Ubuntu machine

I have completed steps till #2 but not able to connect to remote MySQL (using SSH) from R panel. Can someone help me doing that?

As i am very new to this domain, your help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command :

```
mysql -u{DB username} -h{DB IP} -p{Password}
```